# Save form answers for re-sending after initial submit

Tags: php, forms, save, store

I am wanting to set up an application form that can save answers so an applicant can send the form than re-apply with the same saved form values at a later time.

I can set up a php form to send but how can I get the form to save and allow re-send?

thanks

Comment: You can serialize the data using `json_encode($data);` and save it as text in database for example. Then you can use it later in cron script or as a Job which will re-send the unserialized data. Or you can save form data in javascript object and then send contents of the object later. @Robo

Comment: `how can I get the form to save `... There are so many different ways to save data, and so much research you could already do. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: I've used a simple php echo to save the form data but wonder if a single submit button will both save the data and send the data to a recipient?

Comment: It will if you write the code to do that. The button, if it submits a form, will cause the server to run a PHP script. That PHP script can run as many (or as few) commands as you wish.